# Export pandas to csv data but before doing so sort date by least to greatest

Tags: python, pandas

Upon looking and researching online it does seem that there a numerous way of doing this but not sure if it fits the way that I want it for. Personally I would still like my dates as this format "3/30/24". I am extracting data from some which has numerous amount of data and everything works as expected but when I tried to sort my date it just was sorting it lexicographically and this is only when I read from the csv rather than writing because I just want to to test if it could even sort in the first place after writing to it.

```py
data_to_export = {
   "Company Name": ["Mcdonalds","Burgerking"],
    "Delivery Address":["123 lake rd", "124 west rd"],
     "Date": ["3/30/24", "1/23/24"],
     "Customer Name": ["Zack", "Peter"],}
```

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_export)
    df.to_csv(join_move_to, index=False)
```

Above is some of the dummy data just so you can get a quick example than below is how I save it

I did have some sort of sort methods before this but it didn't work so I just deleted it but before writing to how can I let it know that I want to sort by date and keep in mind I still want my format as "(Month/Day/Year) "

I do understand this is a string so it must be converted to some sort of date then sorted but I can not find a way to do that

here is what I tried just so you guys can see

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_export)
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],format="%m/%d/%y")
    df.sort_values(by="Date", inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

Comment: Fix your code for data example which is not runnable in its current form.

Comment: I think what you need is `df.sort_values("Date", key=lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s, format="%m/%d/%y"))`. If so, you have been very close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a custom `key` with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), this will use the defined logic to sort while leaving the data unchanged:

```
(df.sort_values(by='Date', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%y')
   .to_csv(path, index=False)  
)
```

Output csv:

```
Company Name,Delivery Address,Date,Customer Name
Burgerking,124 west rd,1/23/24,Peter
Mcdonalds,123 lake rd,3/30/24,Zack
```

Comment: May I ask is this pretty much the same thing Chris said above because I noticed you put yours in full parenthesis.

Comment: @ABeautifulTrend yes, this is doing the same thing (I hadn't seen the comment), I just chain this to `to_csv` but you could keep it as 2 lines.